# How do I process lines with CRLF, NEL line terminators?

Tags: perl, shift-jis

I need to process a file with shift_jis encoding.  However the line terminators are in a format that im not familar with.

```
> file record.CSV 
record.CSV: Non-ISO extended-ASCII text, with CRLF, NEL line terminators
```

Im using the general:

```
open my $CSV_FILE, "<:encoding(shift_jis)", $filename or die "Could not open: $CSV_FILE : $!";
while (<$CSV_FILE>) {
    chomp;
    # do stuff
}
```

However it is still leaving a CR at the end of each record.

What is the correct way to terminate files of these types?

Comment: Curious: Does this mean that each record in the file is terminated with CR LF NEL?  Or are some records CR LF and others NEL?

Comment: Are you *sure* there are NEL characters? That character isn't present in Shift JIS (or ASCII, for that matter). The character at position 0x15 is NAK.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you do *not* have NEL characters as 0x85 is (in Shift-JIS) part of a multi-byte character sequence. E.g. a set of Shift-JIS files I've got here contains this sequence quite often: "\x8c\x85" which actually represents this Kanji: 桁. So you probably only want to remove the CR. Which you can do with a regex easily enough.

Answer (score 1):

Why not do `$_ =~ s/\r//` manually?

Edit: apparently, you can also do

```
require Encode;
use Unicode::Normalize;

s/\x{0085}//g;
```

to remove the `NEL:   Next Line, U+0085` characters.

Answer (score 0):

You need to consider who's consuming the data and learn more about the environment which produced these files. If it's a plain-vanilla CSV output file you're after in the end, use any old string manipulation you like to get rid of them (and produce CRLF terminators in their stead) and you'll be fine.